# How to achieve smoother GUI transitions in .NET?

Tags: c#, user-interface, user-controls

I've a main windows form which contains several user controls. These user controls contain  single to multiple controls. For instance, one of my user control has 30 check boxes. Especially, when I add this specific user control to my main form during a mouse click event, the form becomes very slow and you can see that each component is drawn one by one. Of course, I don't want my users to see that. I read about double buffering and enable this in my usercontrol and all other controls in my solution. However, this does not seem to improve much of this graphics processing speed. Probably, I could have created this specific usercontrol during form_load and changed its visibility to false and then when the event is triggered I could have set it back to true, but I am sure there is another way to solve this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thirty checkboxes in a *user control* is a usability disaster.  Seeing it crawl while painting doesn't really matter much anymore, your user hates it anyway.  Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255605/render-winforms-controls-more-smoothly/2258241#2258241

Comment: @Hans Passant: You solved my problem anyway. Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't solve the user's problem.  Oh well.

Comment: @mert: Hiding the problem can hardly be seen as a solution. Seriously, use a listbox or something with 30 items instead of 30 separate controls.

Comment: @bic: 30 separate controls should not be a problem for a Windows application. I just don't get it. I can use a listbox but it won't graphically be meaningful for what I am trying to accomplish. Each check mark indicates a capability of a cd-rom. This way it looks nice to me. I could have used images instead of checkboxes but I don't think this would improve its speed.

Comment: @mert: ok, I just did a quick check with a basic winforms project and a usercontrol with 30 checkboxes. I add the usercontrol when the main form is clicked and the result is immediate. There is no visible lag at all. The performance problem you're having would seem to be somewhere else (ie. not rendering). I'd recommend getting a profiler and continue with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For instance, one of my user control has 30 check boxes.

Do all of these check boxes need to be visible at the same time? It might be more productive (and result in a better design) for you to split up these check boxes between different tabs or even different forms.

Comment: Also, a listview with checkboxes or similar would probably help.

Comment: Right, absolutely no reason for that many checkboxes. Split them up into separate forms, or replace entire swaths of them with a *single* more appropriate control (like a `ComboBox`). You also forgot to mention that controls take time to load and render, probably more so than anything else. Reducing the number of controls on a form/window will get it on the screen faster and allow it to be manipulated faster once it's there.

Comment: I agree with you but 30 checkboxes should not be a problem for a Windows application even though I have a bad design here. How do other application work so smoothly with tons of controls being present at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, where my user control, which was made of multiple standard controls, was being drawn very slowly.

To my surprise, I found that compiling in Release mode gave much faster (and acceptable) drawing times than in Debug mode.

I'd give that a go and see if the optimizations make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If 30 check boxes are creating problems then you may distribute your work on different pages. And pages always works faster then windows. So, you may distribute your 30 check boxes on 2 or 3 pages, if you can.

Comment: 30 check boxes should not be a problem for a windows application. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on DoubleBuffering.

Not all controls allow it to be set directly, to work around this subclass the control and set DoubleBuffering in the constructor

Comment: I currently have it exactly like you said but the performance is still slow.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bic suggested checkedListBox or the param code thing does the trick. Thanks.