# Prebuffering Form when minimized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, show, minimize

(I know that there is an answer at SO about this problem. I see it two days before, but now i can't find it)

So. I have app with single Form. App starts minimized in tray. When I restore the Form from tray it start drawing. And it's look terrible on slow PC.
How I can preRender Form (when it not visible), to avoid drawing when he is already displayed?

I use `Hide()` when minimize to tray, and `Show()` to restore.

Comment: Depends.  What are you drawing?

Comment: try calling the `Invalidate` or `Refresh` methods on the form.

Comment: @LarsTech Form contains buttons(a lot of) and one-two textlayers. Just simple interface elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2258241/17034

Comment: @HansPassant Ha, I was about to link your other answer: [How to fix the flickering in User controls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612487/719186)  :-)

Comment: Thanks. Now i try to understand how it work....