# How to switch forms in vb.net SMOOTHLY

Tags: vb.net

I try to write a program to switch between two forms.  My strategy is to create two forms.  The code is below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub switch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles switch.Click
        Me.Visible = False
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 500)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Back_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Back.Click
        Me.Visible = False
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 500)
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, when I do it, I can see the process of disappearing of the form1 and the showing of the form2.  [sorry about the English, I may misused the word here]  Also, the position of two forms are not perfectly matched. One strategy I can think of is to predefined the position(size) of two forms so when they are loaded, they will appear in the exact same position.  However, it is not the case as I showed in the code above. I wonder what is the strategy to make switching between forms smoothly? 
Thanks

Comment: This would work better if your forms were UserControls and you show and hide them in a main form.

Comment: If you see the "process of disappearing" then you are using Windows XP.  Don't use XP, it is not compatible with your user name.  Seeing the Show() method call cause a lot of visible artifacts is pretty normal, Winforms programmers tend to cram too many controls into a window and you tend to notice them taking their turn to paint.  In general easy to fix by double-buffering the window *and* its controls so it snaps onto the screen.  [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2258241/17034).  "Snap" isn't exactly "smoothly", you can change the Opacity property with a Timer.

Comment: thanks you for advice guys.  @HansPassant I am actually using win7.